# Are any rows guaranteed to be grouped together on join to 1:many table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g, inner-join

Take for example the select,

```
select user_id, email_address
from users
     join email on users.id = email.user_id
```

This yields results

```
ANDY   |  andy_one@foo-bar.com
ANDY   |  andy_two@foo-bar.com
JOE    |  joe_one@foo-bar.com
JOE    |  joe_two@foo-bar.com
```

Are Andy and Joes emails guaranteed to grouped together in the result when no order by is provided?  I'm building an application that would join these together and stream the results.  I need to know if I need to explicitly offer the order by clause and incur its performance hit.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The only way to guarantee the order of results is to explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

However, adding an `ORDER BY` doesn't necessarily affect performance.  If the query plan will return ordered results (say, because you're driving off an index) Oracle knows that it doesn't have to do an extra sort.